# IdentityServer3: How to assign ClientSecret to MVC Client?

Tags: identityserver3

I have configured IdentityServer3 with EF and AspNetIdentity. I have 3 MVC client applications. All users and clients are configured in SQL DB. I was able to get it working and users can now log in.

Now I'm trying to add some security around Client & Users and I have few questions related

**1> Does MVC client only works with Implicit Flow?**  I have MVC client and below is it's OWIN startup.

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44314/identity",
                Scope = "openid",
                ClientId = "LocalHostMvcClient",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:34937/",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"                 
            });
        }
    }
```

On IdentityServer, when I change the flow of `LocalHostMvcClient` to any flow (Other than 'Implicit') then client get error `The client application is not known or is not authorized.`. So it looks like for MVC client
    it only works with `Implicit` flow. 
    Is this true?

**2> Is ClientSecret not relevant for `Implicit` flow?**
   I want to use ClientSecret, but looks like it is not relevant for `Implicit` flow. Based on [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html) ClientSecret is relevant to only flows that require secret. If answer to question 1 is true then does that mean i cannot use ClientSecret with `Implicit` Flow?

**3> If i have multiple clients and users. Can we assign a user to a particular client?**
   For example, if i have 3 clients, www.client1.com, www.client2.com,www.client3.com and 2 users User1,User2. I want User1 to be able to login only for www.client1.com 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. ASP.NET MVC can use any OpenID Connect flow. The error you are receiving is due to the client application requesting something it is not allowed to or otherwise being misconfigured in some way. Enable logging in Identity Server and it'll soon tell you why.
2. Client Secret is not used in Implicit, as implicit relies on the requesting url, not any sort of explicit authorization. That's why it's useful for client-side languages.
3. This is authorization logic and should be handled within the client application. For example when they login they would be shown an 'unauthorized' page. Identity Server is for authentication only.